# rails delayed jobs with "whenever" and "delayed_job_active_record"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, whenever

I have never worked on delayed jobs, trying first time.

I used **whenever** and **delayed_job_active_record**. for whenever I followed the instruction at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) like

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
command: wheneverize .
```

and added schedule.rb

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner "Page.save_daily_detail"  #Page is name of model, and save_daily_detail put some entries in database
end
```

than

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

For delayed_job_active_record

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

commands:

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

also in application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

and when I start jobs with

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

it says that jobs start but does nothing.
what 'm I missing here?

Comment: I did not get how crontab and delayed_job inter-linked in your case

Comment: Same thing I want to know, that How to inter-link them

Comment: What functionality u want to build?.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to restart crontab.

```
whenever --update-crontab <xyz_anyname> --set 'environment=production' #update crontab by passing environment
service crond restart # to restart crontab to reflect changes in Linux system
```

Only on linux answer works

Add this line in schedule.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "#{@pre_set_variables[:environment]}"
```

While updating crontab pass environment variable accordingly in local and production.

Comment: Actually I notice that with "whenever --update-crontab" it created cronjob for production mode, so I created it in development mode by setting envirnment, its working now on local.
but not working on server (in development mode)